# Redis: How to store a hashset with 5 fields efficiently

Tags: node.js, memory, redis, memory-efficient

I am working with redis and want to store more than 1 Million keys as a hashset with 5 fields.

At first it looked like that:

```
key : {
a : 1,
b : 2,
c : 3,
d : 4,
e : 5
}
```

1M keys used about 130MB of Memory. Then I found an post from the instagram developers: http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value

So I adapted my approach to:

```
key1 : {
1a : 1,
1b : 2,
1c : 3,
1d : 4,
1e : 5,
2a : 1,
...
}

key2 : {
1a : 1,
1b : 2,
1c : 3,
1d : 4,
1e : 5,
2a : 1,
...
}
...
```

This used more than 200MB for just 500k entries. So is there a better structure within redis my data?

//EDIT

---

Ok so I have an object named 'user' I want to save in redis with 5 fields ('name','email','age', 'gender', 'active'). So at first I used the hmset command to create an entry in redis via nodejs 'redis'-package.

```
userId : {
name : Emil Example,
email : email@stackoverflow.com,
age : 20,
gender : m,
active : true
}
```

So I created 1M entries of dummy data an checked the memory-usage via 'INFO' command. About ~130MB. Then I read the instagram blog and their usage of buckets. So I implemented it with my data (userID : '12345'):

```
12 : {
345name : Emil Example,
345email : email@stackoverflow.com,
345age : 20,
345gender : m,
345active : true
}
```

Of course every userID beginning with '12' would fall into this bucket. After I tried a run with 500k dummy entries I had a usage of more than 500MB. So I just ask myself if I made something wrong or for my case, are there some other optimization options?

P.S: Ofc I adjusted the 'hash-zipmap-max-entries' settings in the config file and started redis using it.

Comment: As stated, your question is primarily opinion-based. Please add a little more detail about what you're trying to optimize, and what you've done so far.

Comment: Do you need to access these hash keys individually? Or you're using `hmget` or `hmgetall` to get an entire hash.

Comment: I need access individually.